# Remove row from a nested list with react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to remove a row from a list when a user wants to delete but i'm finding difficulty doing it. With my code when the user hits delete nothing happens

```
handleExistGroup = (item) => {
  var array = [...this.state.userList];
  var index = array.indexOf(item.id)
  if (index !== -1) {
    array.splice(index, 1);
    this.setState({userList: array});
  }
 }
```

STATE

```
state = {
  userList : [
    {
    id: '1',
    name: 'LOL Group',
    description: 'LOL Group',
    icon: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/brynn/128.jpg'
  },
    {
      id: '2',
      name: 'Fantasy Travel',
      description: 'Travelling',
     icon: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/brynn/128.jpg'
    }
  ]
}
```

VIEW

Comment: Can you share your code via expo snack?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily achieve it by filtering out your array from items with the same `id` as the given one :

```
handleExistGroup = item => {
    this.setState(prev => ({ userList: prev.userList.filter(user => user.id !== item.id) }));
}
```